# Obtain Docker host address WITHOUT 'Docker Desktop for Windows'

Tags: windows, docker, networking

I have docker installed on Windows Server and need to access something running on the host machine. The containers are Windows containers.

All other answers I can find which state `host.docker.internal`, `docker.for.win.localhost` or `docker.for.win.host.internal` **do not work** as you cannot have 'Docker Desktop' installed on a Windows Server machine (these names do not resolve).

This is confirmed by the official [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds):

> The host has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network
> access). We recommend that you connect to the special DNS name
> host.docker.internal which resolves to the internal IP address used by
> the host. This is for development purpose and will not work in a
> production environment outside of Docker Desktop for Windows.

So what's the alternative?

Comment: _"need to access something"_ - what? You can do `docker-compose run /foo/bar docker-container-name`.

Comment: @CodeCaster MariaDB, which for business reasons has to run on the host, not in another container.

Comment: That is ... unfortunate. But then connect to the host on its DNS name, and provide a DNS server (or value)?